# WebApi - Bind from both Uri and Body

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

Is it possible to bind a model from both the Uri and Body?

For instance, given the following:

```
routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "API Default",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);

public class ProductsController : ApiController
{
    public HttpResponseMessage Put(UpdateProduct model)
    {

    }
}

public class UpdateProduct 
{
    int Id { get; set;}
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Is it possible to create a custom binder so that a `PUT` to

> /api/products/1

with a JSON body of:

```
{
    "Name": "Product Name"
}
```

will result in the `UpdateProduct` model populated with `Id = 1` and `Name = "Product Name"`?

**Update**

I understand that I could change the action signature to

```
public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, UpdateProduct model)
{

}
```

However as stated in the question, I specifically want to bind to a single model object

I have also posted this question to the [WebApi Codeplex discussion forum](https://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/discussions/450258)

Comment: If you remove the `Id` from `UpdateProduct` and it to your action signature:  `public HttpResponseMessage Put(int id, UpdateProduct model)` it would also work without any custom model binder.

Comment: Check out this article it seems this is what you need: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/18/mvc-style-parameter-binding-for-webapi.aspx

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this? I'm having the same problem. In my opinion, this is a really dumb and unintuitive behavior.

Comment: Completely unintuitive behaviour... especially that it just works in MVC...

Answer (score 14):

Here's an improved version of odyth's answer that:

1. Works for bodiless requests too, and
2. Gets parameters from the query string in addition to from route values.

For brevity I just post the ExecuteBindingAsyncCore method and a new auxiliary method, the rest of the class is the same.

```
private async Task ExecuteBindingAsyncCore(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext,
        HttpParameterDescriptor paramFromBody, Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var model = await ReadContentAsync(request, type, Formatters, formatterLogger, cancellationToken);

    if(model == null) model = Activator.CreateInstance(type);

    var routeDataValues = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values;
    var routeParams = routeDataValues.Except(routeDataValues.Where(v => v.Key == "controller"));
    var queryStringParams = new Dictionary<string, object>(QueryStringValues(request));
    var allUriParams = routeParams.Union(queryStringParams).ToDictionary(pair => pair.Key, pair => pair.Value);

    foreach(var key in allUriParams.Keys) {
        var prop = type.GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
        if(prop == null) {
            continue;
        }
        var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(prop.PropertyType);
        if(descriptor.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string))) {
            prop.SetValue(model, descriptor.ConvertFromString(allUriParams[key] as string));
        }
    }

    // Set the merged model in the context
    SetValue(actionContext, model);

    if(BodyModelValidator != null) {
        BodyModelValidator.Validate(model, type, metadataProvider, actionContext, paramFromBody.ParameterName);
    }
}

private static IDictionary<string, object> QueryStringValues(HttpRequestMessage request)
{
    var queryString = string.Join(string.Empty, request.RequestUri.ToString().Split('?').Skip(1));
    var queryStringValues = System.Web.HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(queryString);
    return queryStringValues.Cast<string>().ToDictionary(x => x, x => (object)queryStringValues[x]);
}
```

Comment: This looks great. Does this code do everything that the default 'FromBody' *and* 'FromUri' attributes would do, combined ?
Also, do you know for what reason the ASP.NET team decided not to include something like 'FromBodyAndUri' out-of-the-box ? I went through countless blog posts, but can't really find why this would be bad practice... 

All my controllers accept an implementation of an `IRequest<>` ([Jimmy Bogard's Mediator pattern](https://github.com/jbogard/MediatR)), which contain all parameters in one object. Would be great to be able to fill it with both body and uri parameters.

Comment: Thanks! I used this in conjunction with a custom `ParameterBindingAttribute` to use like so `public IHttpActionResult Put([FromUriAndBody]ComplexType param)`

Comment: Konamiman - `System.Web.HttpUtility` needs a reference to `System.Web` which is redundant in a Web API project. It's been suggested to use `System.Net.Http.UriExtensions.ParseQueryString()`. So the code in QueryStringValues() should be like:
`var queryStringValues = request.RequestUri.ParseQueryString();` ...

Comment: @SimonGates can you share your binding attribute code?

Comment: @Langdon yeah sure, I'll try and remember to put a gist up tomorrow when I get in the office.

Comment: @SimonGates Haha, sorry, nevermind, it was far easier than I anticipated. `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)] public sealed class FromStuffAttribute : ParameterBindingAttribute { public override HttpParameterBinding GetBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor) { return new BodyAndUriParameterBinding(descriptor); } }`

Are you still using it? Run into any issues?

Comment: @Langdon haha no worries - I don't recall any issues having used it utilised this in a couple of projects.

Answer (score 8):

You can define your own DefaultActionValueBinder.  Then you can mix and match from body and uri.  Here is a blog post with an example of an MvcActionValueBinder for Web Api.  Making your own DefaultActionValueBinderis a preferred solution because it guarantees the binder will have finished before any other ActionFilterAttribute are executed.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/18/mvc-style-parameter-binding-for-webapi.aspx

**UPDATE:**

I had some trouble with the implementation in the blog post and trying to get it to use my custom media formatters.  Luckily all my request objects extend from a base class of `Request` so I made my own formatter.

in WebApiConfig

```
config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, descriptor => descriptor.ParameterType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Request)) ? new BodyAndUriParameterBinding(descriptor) : null);
```

BodyAndUriParameterBinding.cs

```
public class BodyAndUriParameterBinding : HttpParameterBinding
{
    private IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> Formatters { get; set; }
    private IBodyModelValidator BodyModelValidator { get; set; }
    public BodyAndUriParameterBinding(HttpParameterDescriptor descriptor)
        : base (descriptor)
    {
        var httpConfiguration = descriptor.Configuration;
        Formatters = httpConfiguration.Formatters;
        BodyModelValidator = httpConfiguration.Services.GetBodyModelValidator();
    }

    private Task<object> ReadContentAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, Type type,
        IEnumerable<MediaTypeFormatter> formatters, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var content = request.Content;
        if (content == null)
        {
            var defaultValue = MediaTypeFormatter.GetDefaultValueForType(type);
            return defaultValue == null ? Task.FromResult<object>(null) : Task.FromResult(defaultValue);
        }

        return content.ReadAsAsync(type, formatters, formatterLogger, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override Task ExecuteBindingAsync(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var paramFromBody = Descriptor;
        var type = paramFromBody.ParameterType;
        var request = actionContext.ControllerContext.Request;
        var formatterLogger = new ModelStateFormatterLogger(actionContext.ModelState, paramFromBody.ParameterName);
        return ExecuteBindingAsyncCore(metadataProvider, actionContext, paramFromBody, type, request, formatterLogger, cancellationToken);
    }

    // Perf-sensitive - keeping the async method as small as possible
    private async Task ExecuteBindingAsyncCore(ModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, HttpActionContext actionContext,
        HttpParameterDescriptor paramFromBody, Type type, HttpRequestMessage request, IFormatterLogger formatterLogger,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var model = await ReadContentAsync(request, type, Formatters, formatterLogger, cancellationToken);

        if (model != null)
        {
            var routeParams = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values;
            foreach (var key in routeParams.Keys.Where(k => k != "controller"))
            {
                var prop = type.GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
                if (prop == null)
                {
                    continue;
                }
                var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(prop.PropertyType);
                if (descriptor.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
                {
                    prop.SetValue(model, descriptor.ConvertFromString(routeParams[key] as string));
                }
            }
        }

        // Set the merged model in the context
        SetValue(actionContext, model);

        if (BodyModelValidator != null)
        {
            BodyModelValidator.Validate(model, type, metadataProvider, actionContext, paramFromBody.ParameterName);
        }
    }
}
```

Request.cs

```
public abstract class Request : IValidatableObject
{
    public virtual IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
    {
        yield return ValidationResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, looks like a great solution and i've used your suggestion in our API but i'm having some trouble the values remain empty. My gues is i'm doing something wrong in WebAPIconfig. My code is `code`config.ParameterBindingRules.Insert(0, descriptor => descriptor.ParameterType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseApiController)) ? new BodyAndUriParameterBinding(descriptor) : null);
            `code`

Comment: @Gregory Just updated my answer to make it more clear. All my models extend from `Request` you put that all your models extend from `BaseApiController`, which would be crazy if true. Ensure all your models extend from the request class above and change `descriptor.ParameterType.IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseApiController))` to `descriptor.ParameterType.IsSubclassOf(typeof (Request))`

Answer (score 5):

Alright, I came up with a way to do it. Basically, I made an action filter which will run after the model has been populated from JSON. It will then look at the URL parameters, and set the appropriate properties on the model. Full source below:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Web.Http.Controllers;
using System.Web.Http.Filters;


public class UrlPopulatorFilterAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        var model = actionContext.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault();
        if (model == null) return;
        var modelType = model.GetType();
        var routeParams = actionContext.ControllerContext.RouteData.Values;

        foreach (var key in routeParams.Keys.Where(k => k != "controller"))
        {
            var prop = modelType.GetProperty(key, BindingFlags.IgnoreCase | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            if (prop != null)
            {
                var descriptor = TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(prop.PropertyType);
                if (descriptor.CanConvertFrom(typeof(string)))
                {
                    prop.SetValueFast(model, descriptor.ConvertFromString(routeParams[key] as string));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If you have other ActionFilterAttributes that depend on the model being full bound this solution wont work as ActionFilterAttributes do not have a guaranteed order of operations.

Comment: What is SetValueFast?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you, this should work out of the box, e.g. this works for me:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(TempModel model)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Test: " + model.Id +", " + model.Name;

        return View("About");
    }

public class TempModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

and on the request: localhost:56329/Home/Test/22
with body:{"Name":"tool"}

I have my model's properties set accordingly to 22 and "tool".

Comment: Felix - I beleive it will work for MVC but I'm trying to get it working for a WebApi project

Comment: Right, my bad, wasn't using web api, so can't really tell, i believe you seen this http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2012/04/16/how-webapi-does-parameter-binding.aspx already. As I understood you need to create custom Formatter to achieve this