# MVC URL: show 1 parameter & hide second

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, url, model-view-controller, routes

Suppose I have URL as

http://someurl.com/Search?q=a&page=8

(Above mentioned `URL` is getting called throug `AJAX`, in `MVC4.paging`)

What I want is to show only upto http://someurl.com/Search?q=a

I want to hide my second `parameter` which is page=8

Is this possible?

EDIT: More confusion to add.

```
<a data-ajax="true" data-ajax-loading="#divLoading" data-ajax-method="POST" data-ajax-mode="replace" data-ajax-success="successPaging" data-ajax-update="#searchresults" href="/Search?q=a&amp;page=1" title="Go to first page">&lt;&lt;</a>
```

Is button of Next in my Paging, it is making an AJAX request, So I don't know how to change GET to POST for this.

Comment: why do you want to do that?

anyway, what you want, is do a "POST" and have some parameters in url, and some in body. Take a look at this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645877/webapi-bind-from-both-uri-and-body

Comment: hide? if you don't want your `queryStrings` to be visible in the url, you should `POST` those variables in the request body or better use a `form`

Comment: @ManishMishra , I know I can POST, but I want to show 1 (q) parameter in queryString.

Comment: then make your url have that parameter `q` and then do the `POST` on the url anyway with rest of the parameters.

Comment: I have edited my question, please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The URL isn't there just for looks; it's telling the server what resource is being requested, and in the case of a query string, that's information the server needs to return a response. `http://someurl.com/Search?q=a` is a *completely* different resource than `http://someurl.com/Search?q=a&page=8`. With a GET request, all you have is the URL, so all the information the server needs must be in the URL. What others in the comments are telling you to do is use a POST request, which among other things includes a *post body*. In other words, you can pass information to the server *both* in the URL and in the post body. That allows you to remove the `page` parameter from the URL and include it in the post body instead. That's the only way you can achieve what you want.

That said, strictly speaking, a POST is inappropriate for fetching a resource like this. POST should be used to update or modify a resource or to call some atomic method in an API scenario. It can also be used for the creation of resources, although PUT is more appropriate there. GET is supposed to be used to return a resource which is not variable. For example, any request to `http://someurl.com/Search?q=a&page=8` should always return the same response no matter what client requests it. And, it's even less important what URL is actually being used because the user does not see it at all, since you're requesting it via AJAX (it won't show in the navigation bar). Just keep it as a GET request and leave the parameters as they are.

Comment: Thanks, I know keeping as it is is good idea, but my manager has asked me to do what I have questioned. So now should I consider that what I have asked is no possible?

Comment: Not while keeping it a regular old GET request.