# Using FromUri OR FromBody in MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

I would like to expose my POST method in a way that allows users call it with parameters either encoded in the url *or* written inside the request body. Pseudocode:

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromUri, FromBody] parameters)
{
    //..
}
```

It isn't even possible via exposing **two** methods:

```
public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromUri] parameters)
public HttpResponseMessage MyMethod([FromBody] parameters)
```

Because they have the same signature. How to achieve this in a simple way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it out of the box; if you try to use both the attributes together you will get this fine error: *Can't bind parameter 'xxx' because it has conflicting attributes on it.*

Two possible solution:

1. Use two different methods, but with two different verbs (one get, one post, for example) - easy way
2. Use only `[FromUri]` and use a custom action filter (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17645877/webapi-bind-from-both-uri-and-body)) to check for body content and, if present, manually parse it and bind it to the correct method parameters - less easy way, but more powerful.

Hope it helps :)